# Animate.css on scroll bug chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I use [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to implant animations on element when scrolling.
My elements have the class `.fadeInRight` and are `hidden`.
When they appear on scroll, I add the class visible who refer to

```
{visibility:visible;}.
```

I see the fade animation on Safari, but on Chrome an Firefox the element just appear, without fading, any ideas?

{EDIT}
Yep
Here is the element html

```
<section class="Informations tadam fadeInLeft">
Some text
</section>
```

My js

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
                $('.tadam').each(function(){
                var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
                var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+(window.innerHeight * 0.9)) {
                        $(this).addClass("animated visible");
                    }
                });
            });
```

And my CSS for these two class

```
.tadam{visibility:hidden;}
.visible{visibility: visible;}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide some HTML? or link to page to see how it looks.. Am unable to reproduce it as it works in chrome

Comment: Started happening to me a few days ago and can't figure it. Did you ever fix your issue? Chrome/Firefox (linux) not working, but works smooth as butter on all other (except Vivaldi where it doesn't even just pop in)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you make a transition from "hidden" to "visible", this property is not animatable.

If your element `visibility` is always visible (or default) and you use a transition from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` it will work.

So your css should look like this:

```
.tadam{opacity: 0;}
.visible{opacity: 1;}
```

If you absolutely need to use the visibility you should set a timeout between your visible class and the animate class like this:

```
var $this = $(this).addClass("visible");
setTimeout(function(){
    $this.addClass("animated");
},10); // 10 should be enough, if it doesn't work, add a little more
```

(Better late than never I guess)